# Add Bittrex API Results from Loop into Dataframe

Tags: python, json, api, dataframe

I am new to python. By following code from others I have put together the following code. The code provide the output from "GetLatestTick" by looping though code for each "pair" in list under the `__name/main__` section. I can even perform calculation on the line being processed. How can I organized this output into a `DataFrame` for sorting and other manipulation?

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
import requests, json
from tabulate import tabulate

def bittrex(lock, pair):
    lock.acquire()
    #print(pair)
    get_request_link = ('https://bittrex.com/Api/v2.0/pub/market/GetLatestTick?marketName='
                        + pair + '&tickInterval=thirtyMin')
    api = requests.get(get_request_link)
    data = json.loads(api.text)

    for i in data:
        if i == 'result':
            for h in data[i]:
                print(pair,h['O'],h['H'],h['L'],h['C'],h['V'],h['BV'],
                      (((h['O'])/(h['H']))-1),h['T'])

            lock.release()
            return data

def main():
    bitt_all = bittrex(lock, pair)  # This still required

if __name__ == '__main__':

    lock = Lock()
    pair = ['BTC-MUE','USD-ETH','USDT-TRX','USDT-BTC']

    for pair in pair:
        Process(target=bittrex, args=(lock, pair)).start()
```

Comment: For some reason all code is not listed correctly. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Do you need the output from the Process id buffer in your Dataframe?